# How do I create a generic class that takes as its generic type a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

Basically, I want to write a wrapper for all ICollection<> types.  Lets call it DelayedAddCollection.  It should take any ICollection as its .

Furthermore, I need access to that ICollection type's generic type as the Add method needs to restrict its parameter to that type.

The syntax I would imagine would look something like this...

```
public DelayedAddConnection<T>: where T:ICollection<U> {
   ....

   public void Add(U element){
     ...
   }
}
```

What is the real correct syntax to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add another generic type parameter:

```
public class DelayedAddConnection<T, U> where T : ICollection<U>
{

}
```

Comment: Tbank you, this was driving me nuts :)

Comment: @user430788 -  Is there any reason you need a type for the collection, instead of it just being `ICollection<T>`?

Comment: I needed the collection type because I was instantiating it internally.  But having implemented it this way I think I can pass it in in the constructor and it will be cleaner, so thanks...

Answer (score 0):

So, for future reference the final, cleanest version of this idea I implemented  thanks to all the suggestions and comments was this:

```
public class DelayedUpdateCollection<U>: ICollection<U> 
{

    ICollection<U> collection;


    public DelayedUpdateCollection(ICollection<U> coll){
        collection = coll;
    }

    ...
```